# Can I change terminal type used to login through Net::SSH in perl?

Tags: ssh, perl

When I login on some particular server through Net::SSH in perl (which I do not have admin access to), I get the following error:

```
 %SECURITY-SSHD-4-WARNING_LOGIN : The requested term-type '' is not supported
```

(I also don't want to change my terminal type permanently).

part of my code as below,

```
 my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
                host => "X.X.X.X", 
                user => 'bnegrao', 
                raw_pty => 1
  );
    eval
    {
         $ssh->login();
    };
```

Is it possible to change the terminal type just when logging through Net::SSH in perl?

Answer (score 1):

The perl code is just running ssh, which exports TERM from the environment, so you can just change the perl environment just before the login:

```
$ENV{TERM} = "vt100";
$ssh->login();
```

If necessary, you can save it first and restore it immediately after the login call.